# Плавная смена картинок js и css?

Tags: jquery, css3, css, javascript

добрый день есть такой скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#example p:first").css("display", "block");

jQuery.fn.timer = function() {
if(!$(this).children("p:last-child").is(":visible")){
$(this).children("p:visible")
.css("display", "none")
.next("p").css("display", "block");

}
else{
$(this).children("p:visible")
.css("display", "none")
.end().children("p:first")
.css("display", "block");
}

}

window.setInterval(function() {
$("#example").timer();
}, 5000);

});
```

он просто меняет каждые 5 сек картинки заключенные в блоки <p></p> за счет замены свойства display с ноне на блок- я хочу сделать что бы было плавно но как впаять opacity что бы было кросбраузерно и кошерно не представлю??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте вместо .css('...), [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) и [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

Comment: так?
    
    $(this).children("p:visible")
    .fadeOut("1000"("display", "none"))
    .next("p").fadeIn("1000",("display", "block"));

Comment: Нет, fadeIn и fadeOut и так помимо прозрачности меняют значение свойства display. fadeIn делает dislay: block; , fadeOut display: none;. В вашем случае: $(this).children("p:visible").fadeOut().next("p").fadeIn();